# what is Get.create() in the Getx package and what it does

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

reading the `Getx` package documentation, I faced this method:

```
  Get.create<ShoppingController>(() => ShoppingController());
```

and it says:

> Get.create(()=>Controller()) will generate a new Controller each time you call Get.find(),

but, I don't seem to understand what this means and how it differs from the `Get.put()` and `Get.lazyPut()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for that question.

The big difference between

```
Get.create<ShoppingController>(() => ShoppingController());
```

And :

```
Get.put(ShoppingController());
```

Both of them are used in injecting dependencies in the a Flutter app, But `Get.put<T>(T())` injects it just one time and whenever we call `Get.find<T>()` it looks up for that exact dependency and return it, so we can rememeber this:

`Get.put<T>(())` inject a dependency and whatever time we call `Get.find<T>()` across the entire app, the same `T` is returned.

In the other side, `Get.create<V>(() => V)` also inject a dependency in a Flutter app, **But** every time we call `Get.find<V>()`, it doesn't return the same `V`, it creates a new instance of `V`, then return it, so we can rememeber this:

`Get.create<V>(() => V)` don't return the same instance, it creates a new one every time `Get.find<V>()` is called.

**Get.put(T()) :**

```
class ControllerOne extends GetxController {
int number = 10;
increment() {
 number += 10;
 }
}


final controllerOne =  Get.put<ControllerOne>(ControllerOne());

final controllerOneFinder = Get.find<controllerOne>();

controllerOneFinder.increment();

final controllerOneSecondFinder = Get.find<controllerOne>();

print(controllerOneFinder.number); // 20

print(controllerOneSecondFinder.number); // 20
```

it stay the same.

**Get.create(() =>T) :**

```
class ControllerTwo extends GetxController {
int secondNumber = 10;
increment() {
 secondNumber += 10;
 }
}


final controllerTwo =  Get.create<ControllerTwo>(() => (ControllerTwo());

final controllerTwoFinder = Get.find<ControllerTwo>();

controllerTwoFinder.increment();

final controllerTwoSecondFinder = Get.find<ControllerTwo>();


print(controllerTwoFinder.number); // 20

print(controllerTwoSecondFinder.number); // 10
```

Each one is different than the other. (controllerTwoSecondFinder == controllerTwoFinder) is `false`.